# AngularJS $resource - Call the method via a variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax

I have an Angular `$resource` as

```
var Client = $resource('/api/clients/:id',{id : '@id'}, {
                           query: { method: 'GET' })
```

I want to be able to call, say `query()` or `save()` via a variable. I.e. I want to say

```
var method = 'query';
Client[method]()
```

But this returns an error: `Unexpected token [`

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an object, which is why you get the error. You can call the method like so:

```
Client.query();
```

If you really want to call it via a variable you could map it to an object and call it that way, I wouldn't recommend it though:

```
var resources = {
   query: Client.query,
   somethingElse: Client.somethingElse
};
var type = 'query';

resources[type]();
```

Comment: Okay, so there is no way of doing this other than the map method?

Comment: I am pretty sure not, nothing is mentioned in the documentation either.

Comment: Okay thanks for all the help. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as it allows me!